# How to get the values of the selected item from a listiew in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have already successfully passed values inside a listview from one layout to another. But my problem is I can only pass the very first value inside the list view but not what  I selected. What I want is to pass the selected value to the layout.

```
  public void reuseUnit() {


            TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLUnitName);
            TextView tg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtG);
            TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLNoofBulbs);
            TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLNoOfFans);
            String name=t1.getText().toString();
            Intent RuseName = new Intent(CreateNewUnit.this,
                    HomePage.class);
            ;
            int gG= Integer.valueOf(tg.getText().toString());
            int Rbulb= Integer.valueOf(t2.getText().toString());
            int RFans= Integer.valueOf(t3.getText().toString());

            RuseName.putExtra("keyRName",name);
            RuseName.putExtra("keyG",gG);
            RuseName.putExtra("keyRbulbs",Rbulb);
            RuseName.putExtra("keyRFans",RFans);
            startActivity(RuseName);

                                  }
```

Comment: Use an adapter for your list. Complete tutorial can be found here : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 final ListView listvw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);

  listvw.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int 
      myItemInt, long mylng) {
    String selectedFromList =(String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));

   }                 
    });
```

try like this this is an example for you

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I know what didi you ment by the "lv" please?

Comment: oh sorry its not lv it should be listvw (variable which i initialized above in my code.. if you happy wth answer vote up :)

Comment: It is not giving the selected item. I tired it several times but it is not giving the selected value